# Count the number of times an id appears across two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `matches` and a `teams` tables. Here's a [Db Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eeDQ7LZ8AJd611ihQs6NL2/1). I'm using Postgres.

They look like this:

```
matches table

 id_match | id_home | id_away |      date_time
----------+---------+---------+---------------------
        1 |       1 |       2 | 2018-11-03 16:30:00
        2 |       1 |       3 | 2019-11-03 16:30:00
        3 |       2 |       3 | 2019-11-03 16:30:00
        4 |       3 |       1 | 2020-11-03 16:30:00

teams table

 id_team |      club      | shorthand
---------+----------------+-----------
       1 | Vinica         | VIN
       2 | Kolpa          | KOL
       3 | Crnomelj       | CRN
       4 | Klub Študentov | KBŠ
       5 | Zilje          | ZLJ
       6 | Preloka        | PRK
```

I'm trying to query and join the two to get:

```
team name | total number of matches
----------+--------------------------
Vinica    | 3
Kolpa     | 2
Crnomelj  | 3
```

The hard bit that I find is the fact that the `team id` can appear in **two columns** of the matches table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unpivot the data using a lateral join.  Then join and aggregate:

```
select t.club, count(*)
from matches m cross join lateral
     (values (m.id_home), (m.id_away)
     ) v(id_team) join
     teams t
     on t.id_team = v.id_team
group by t.club;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eeDQ7LZ8AJd611ihQs6NL2/1) is the fiddle.

Comment: Thank you! That’s clever! Will accept as answer when it lets me.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff,  Can you explain where the `v` (in `v(id_team)`) comes from and how this `v` works, please?  I understand the `matches as m` and `teams as t` concept.  I do not understand the v.

Comment: @tommygibbons … “v” is a table aliasa

Comment: @Gordon Linoff,  Thank you Gordon.  I do not understand where or how Postgres knows what table the `v` alias is assigned to?  I cannot see this in the code though it works as expected!  Have I missed something?